# Is using Elastic Beanstalk worth the hassle if using Nginx?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

AWS Elastic Beanstalk still doesn't support Nginx out of the box for PHP, Python, or Ruby. Regardless of how strange that is, I'm wondering whether it is worth the hassle to configure my existing PHP web application to be an Elastic Beanstalk app.

Are [the various hacks for this](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/09/14/replacing-apache-with-nginx-on-elastic-beanstalk/) as trivial as they seem? What additional hurdles might I expect?

Comment: You'd probably be better off setting up a cluster with AWS OpsWorks.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks I hadn't heard of OpsWorks but in briefly looking through their documentation, this does look like what I need. Feel free to add this as an answer and I'll upvote it. Beanstalk might seem better if you haven't built any aspect of your application in which case you can just follow the Beanstalk directions. But if you already have your application fully functional, it seems like a lot and potentially deal-breaking amount of re-configuring (https, memcache, etc.) to get it compatible with Beanstalk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beanstalk is great if you want to go with a mostly default install, but you're likely better off building an [AWS OpsWorks](http://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/) cluster if you want to run a custom infrastructure that's extensible in the long-term.